# Java - ServiceLoader - Intellij cannot find implementation class files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, serviceloader

### Intro

I am trying to create multiple services which fuzz the input (for testing purposes. I am using the concept of dependency injection using `java.util.ServiceLoader<T>` feature. I am using IntelliJ for this project.

**Github Project Link: https://github.com/ghoshabhi/java-service-loader**

### Problem

I have created a `META-INF/services` directory with one file within it: `htmlfuzzing.spi.HtmlFuzzer` mentioning the path to my implementation class (`htmlfuzzing.TagReplacer`). I was trying to create a structure similar to [an example on Oracle's website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html#dictionary-service-example).

I also went ahead and marked the `META-INF` directory as `resources` by going to `Project Settings > Modules` :

[image]

Here's what my `output` directory looks like:

[image]

As you can see above, the implementation class' class files are not added to the `out/` directory.

Here's my complete directory structure:

[image]

### Question

I am obviously doing something wrong here, but I am not able to understand what. What is the correct way of adding or marking the `META-INF` directory as the `resources` or what is the correct way to include all the service implementation classes?

Any help or hint towards solving this is appreciated.

### EDIT - 1

Added `src/resource` folder and placed the `META-INF` directory within it. But I still don't see the implementation class' class files in the `out` directory.

Also, one thing I have noticed is as soon as I mark any directory as `resource` in the project structure - it vanishes from the project view pan on the left. Anything odd there?

[image]

Comment: In my opinion the way you have defined it you need one more folder between your  src and your META-INF folder and you need to map this folder as resource folder. The point is that you want in your bin folder to have the folder META-INF picked up.  Make a folder src/resource/META-INF and mark the resource folder as resource folder

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov: I did as you said, but I still don't see any implementation classes in the `out` dir and they are not returned by the `serviceLoader.iterator()`. I have updated my question with a screenshot of the newly added `resource` dir.

Comment: I actualy dont use IntelliJ :) just it made me impression that you specify straight the meta inf as a resource folder which I dont find very correct to be honest. But in your place i would create one maven project and stop dealing with IDE specific settings. I use Eclipse, but my projects are configured as maven projects.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @AlexandarPetrov, but I have a restriction to not use maven. Need no build steps or anything :/

Comment: I expect that if you place the META-INF/services straight into your src folder and don\t declare the META-INF folder as resource it will end up in your binary folder and then it will work.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov: I have tried that too, i.e. simply have the META-INF as a folder wihtin `ModuleName/src/` - that module's class files do not end up in the `out` dir.

Comment: I can see you don't have the same problem I had (but you may want to double-check in the file system anyway) but for some reason, IntelliJ had the following directory under resources: `META-INF.services`, as opposed to `META-INF/services`... Usually, you can create a folder and a subfolder using a `.`, but apparently not always... :|